# Azure API Management without Developer Portal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I started to use Azure API Management with the Consumption Tier. After importing the first API into the API Gateway and assigning a product to it, I recognized that for the Consumption Tier no Developer Portal seems to be available. So I have no possibility to give Developer the chance to register for my public APIs.

So how can Developer register for my products? Do I have to write my custom Developer Portal?

Regards

Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, consumption tier does not have dev portal available. Your only options are to either create your own dev portal utilizing our API to manage subscriptions, or migrate to dedicated SKU, which is a manual process at the moment.

Comment: Sorry, internal (i guess) abbreviation. SKU means tier. Dedicated tiers are: Developer, Basic, Standard, and Premium. In contrast to consumption tier which is, well, Consumption.